# Android sprite sheet animation behaviour changes based on android:minSdkVersion

Tags: android, garbage-collection, sprite-sheet

I did the tutorial below on android animation and sprite sheets and everything works great until I change the

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> in my manifest from 3 to 10
```

http://warriormill.com/2009/10/adroid-game-development-part-1-gameloop-sprites/comment-page-1/#comment-1091

I noticed two very strange things that happen:

1. The Garbage Collector is running very frequently and performance is
   significantly lower resulting in Out of Memory Errors.
2. The animated sprites aren't being drawn properly because the
   coordinates of the sprite location on the sheet is off.

Could someone please explain to me why this is happening? Additionally, I'm feeling like I just should use the min-sdk version 3 because it performs faster.  Is that ok?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> is what was changed in the manifest